# Turn up vs Come up - Appear?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Turn up and Come up are able to mean "appear"?

When can I use come up or turn up?

Comment: Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Contrast...

> 1: *You never know what will **turn** up*
>    2: *You never know what will **come** up*

The specific context may force one interpretation of the other, but I'm sure that *on average* people would use ***turn up*** for desirable future possibilities, and ***come up*** for undesirable ones.

---

For a slightly different meaning, contrast...

> 3: *John **turned** up at the pub last night*
>    4: *John **came** up at the pub last night*

Again, context can make all the difference. But my *default* assumption would be that if John ***turned up***, that would mean he appeared (unexpectedly) at the pub. If he ***came up***, that probably just means we talked about him, but he wasn't present (he came up in conversation).

Comment: But wouldn't he have *come up to the pub*? *He came up at the pub* seems to have an unfortunate *entendre*.

Comment: Sorry I now realise I made that last comment not having read your answer properly. *Came up to the pub* would mean that he appeared in person. *John came up at the pub* would suggest his name came up in conversation. Apologies. For some reason the system will not let me delete the earlier comment..

Comment: @WS2: Not sure what you mean by "unfortunate entendre". Suppose I phoned John from the pub and said *I expect you'll **turn/come** up here later* (judiciously avoiding any prepositions). Maybe my *(unexpectedly)* doesn't precisely fit all contexts, but there's definitely something of that general sense in *turn up*. And it doesn't require a particularly contrived context for **I expect you'll come up...* to be used to mean *I expect we'll talk about you...*

Comment: I feel sure we don't disagree with any of this. There has been some talking at cross purposes, occasioned by my not reading your answer properly. Sorry, I was plumbing the depths with my *unfortunate entendre* suggestion *John came up at the pub* - but let's not go any further down that particular road!

Comment: @WS2: Yeah, I don't think we're *disagreeing* in any meaningful sense. But I was kinda hoping you might be able to help me formulate some more complete explanation of why despite the strong "unexpectedly" connotations of ***turning up***, it's perfectly natural to say you ***expect** him to turn up*. Maybe it's just that if you turn up, the implication is simply that your appearance wasn't deliberately and publicly ***pre-arranged***.

Comment: I think with *turning up* there is inevitably some element of the unexpected about it. It seems to me to cover the full spectrum from a completely chance occurrence - *You will never believe who turned up out of the blue* - to somebody indicating that they hope to come *I can't make any promises but the likelihood is that I shall turn up*. Or the barman who says *he usually turns up about 9 o'clock on a Thursday evening*. The expression also carries a tone of informality, even if it be an ironic informality.

Answer (score 0):

When used of people, they have different meanings; only 'turn up' is used as a MWV:

> John turned up.

(We didn't know if he was going to come - quite possibly not.)

> John came up.

This is probably a straight directional (... the stairs) or slightly metaphorical (... from the Midlands) usage.

When used of making a discovery, only 'turn up' is used:

> Look what(/s) turned up in the recycling pile.

With names, only 'come up' is used:

> We were thinking of opening batsmen, and your name came up.